# module handle through base address

Tags: c++, windows, module

Im' trying to get the module handle of a module in C++ on windows.
My problem is that I have only the base address and File handle of the module but GetModuleHandle receives only its name as a parameter.
Is there a way in c++ on windows to obtain a module handle without knwoing the module's name?

Comment: The base address *is* the module handle.  Simply cast it to HMODULE.  Works on both x86 and x64 versions of Windows.

Comment: How do you have file handle and base address. That makes no sense whatsoever. Hans is right, base address == module handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using [`GetModuleHandleEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683200%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) `(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS | GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT, (LPCTSTR)lpBaseAddress, &module)`?

Answer (score 1):

Use GetModuleHandleEx if you use WindowsXP or later. For previous Windows versions like Windows2000 this function is not available, but there is alternate solution, check comments at the bottom of this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683200(v=VS.85).aspx